# apache2 webdav givng a 405 error after enabling ssl certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04, webdav, mod-ssl

Apache 2.4.29 \ Ubuntu 18.04 LTE

The webdav was working fine before I was using an SSL connection, that is, when I was using a "http://" URL to access the folders in my server (which is pc with ubuntu running apache). I was using cadaver to check if I could make files in the directory where webdav is enabled.

But as soon I enabled the SSL connection with the help of a self-signed certificate, I was able to establish a connection with the help of a "https://" URL, but could not write anything in the directory because of a 405 error.
[here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PuDY.png)

My config file looks like this

```
DavLockDB /var/www/DavLock
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined



    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/server.key



    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    Alias /webdav /webdav

    <Location /webdav>
        Options Indexes
        DAV On
        <Limit GET PROPFIND POST OPTIONS MKCOL PUT DELETE LOCK UNLOCK COPY MOVE PROPPATCH>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "webdav"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
        Require valid-user
        </Limit>
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to enable webdav over a SSL connection because some devices have disabled 'http://' and the connection and require a 'https://' connection to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently Apache2 has two different config files for pointing out the available sites. By default those files are '000-default.conf' for http:// connection and 'default-ssl.conf' for https:// enabled connection. I had to write configuration for webdav on the file 'default-ssl.conf' for the webdav to work with https:// url.